# Is it a good practice to read url parameters in angular service?

Tags: angular, service, angular-router

In angular, is it a good practice to read parameters from URL inside a service?

Service will not be loaded with pages, so is there any chance that it will read the old values?

What are the pros and cons?

From angular site:

**[ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)**: Provides access to information about a route associated with a component that is loaded in an outlet

Comment: I would use it in component in constructor in component's ts file rather.

Comment: You asked for the "pros and cons" of using a service.  However you didn't specify any alternative.  Using a service vs doing what?  A component?  A Route Guard? Something else entirely?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: using ActivatedRoute inside a service for any reason to read value from URL!